# What do terminal commands ls > wc and ls | wc show?

Tags: linux, bash

I know what the commands ls and wc do, but I can not find out what ls > wc and ls | wc will show. Can someone please help me flush out the meaning of this commands?

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: @JamesBrown As we already have tons of questions related to use shells in general, it is quite common to take the questions as shell programming which is quite fine for SO. Only my two cents...

Comment: @Klaus - occasionally a few do slip through, true, but... basic linux shell command questions don't belong here. Arguably some of the script-based questions fit, since they're doing logic flow etc. But not this.

Comment: @AIA: Please read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/).

Answer (score 3):

`ls | wc` The output from the ls command is piped into the wc command. So it will count the words which are in the output of ls. So you see simply the number of files read by ls.

`ls > wc` This creates a new file in your current working directory with the name `wc` with the output of your `ls` command. The program `wc` is not used here, simply a new file with the same name is created. You can simply look into this new file with your favorite editor or simply use `cat` for it.

Comment: Thank you, very much. It all makes sense.

Comment: @AlA: Instead of say "Thanks", please accept the answer and/or upvote. That is how we "pay" on SO :-)